# perl-mode indentation continuation

Tags: perl

```
$defs = {
   "key1" => 1,       # indented correct with tab
       "key2" => 2,   # indented too much, should align with key1
       "key3" => 3,   # keeps indentation from here on
};
```

With regular perl-mode in Emacs 26.5 the indentation is "staggered" like above, where key2 and key3 are not aligned with key1 when tab is pressed, but should be. How to make perl-mode do that? (not cperl-mode).

Comment: Why do you not want to use `cperl-mode`?

Comment: I would have to learn it to get the same behaviour and face, which I set up some time in 1995 and have forgotten all about, because it works.

Comment: Cool, I can understand that. I do recommend you give `cperl-mode` a try. Think of it as more of a superset of `perl-mode`. And, there's always emacs.SE to help smooth the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `perl-continued-statement-offset`.

```
(setq perl-continued-statement-offset 0)
```

See it's documentation (via `Ctrl-H v`):

```
perl-continued-statement-offset is a variable defined in ‘perl-mode.el’.
Its value is 4

  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘integerp’.

Documentation:
Extra indent for lines not starting new statements.

You can customize this variable.
```

You'll notice its (default) value is "4"; the number of spaces your `"key2"` is indented. If you change this while a `perl-mode` buffer is active you'll have to manually re-indent the code in that buffer. Setting his may negatively change other indentation, so keep an eye out.

Comment: Sure does .. gratitude. Cruisin' again, thanks.

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept that answer. 

Comment: I tried to press the up arrow, but I am one of low repute.